# Implementing gRPC with Nginx in a React.js and Node.js Application

Tags: reactjs, node.js, nginx, grpc-node, grpc-web

I am currently facing challenges in establishing communication between the gRPC client, implemented in React.js, and the gRPC server, implemented in Node.js. On the client side, I have successfully generated the gRPC files from the .proto file, but encounters issues when attempting to initiate communication with the server. Despite setting up the necessary configurations, it seems like the client is unable to connect or send requests to the server.

I would greatly appreciate guidance on the proper steps or any potential pitfalls that may be hindering the successful communication between the React.js client and Node.js server using gRPC. Additionally, if there are specific code examples, configurations, or best practices that should be followed in this context, I would be grateful for any insights provided.